# How to retrieve the text Effective Date from the text node within th node using Selenium and Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I want to retrieve text **Effective Date** from the below image. How to write xpath for this?

Snapshot of the HTML:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, however I would try to do it with CSS.

With XPath:

```
String spanText= driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                   "//*[@class='yourDiv']/.//span[contains(@id,'yourLabel')]"))
              .getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

With CSS:

```
String spanText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#IdOfDiv span.selectLabel"))
              .getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Answer (score 0):

The text **Effective Date** is within a *text node*. So to retrieve the text you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the  `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("table.data_form.label tbody > tr > th")))).toString());
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//table[@class='data_form label']//tbody/tr/th")))).toString());
  ```

Answer (score 0):

With Selenium, I usually prefer to use the `id` locator when it is available. In this case, for your target element, there is no id. My next option would be to see if I can use the `name` property which is also not available here. So I usually use `xpath` as my last choice, not that it is not good but is slow. However `xpath` is usually very capable, you can almost locate anything with it. In your case, here is the locator I would use:

```
String elementLocator = "//span[@id='rightmandatory']/parent::th";
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath(elementLocator)).getText();
```

If the `getText()` method reads the text from the span element, then you can alternatively replace it with `.getAttribute("innerHTML")`. Of course, there are other locators that you can use here, but you ask for the xpath. I hope this helps.